# UIBarButtonItem doesn't work when created as a property, but does when created in a function

Tags: swift

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` in the right side of my navigation that has an image of a gear and presents my settings view controller. I can get it to work properly when I create the button in `setupNavigationBar()`, but it doesn't work if I create the button as a property. I can't wrap my head around what would be different about these two scenarios. The button is present in both situations, but the functionality isn't.

**This version doesn't work**

```
class DecksController: UIViewController {

    let settingsBarButton: UIBarButtonItem = {
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "settings"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(presentSettings))
        return barButton
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupNavigationBar()
    }

    @objc func presentSettings() {
        let settingsController = SettingsController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsController, animated: true)
    }

    func setupNavigationBar() {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = settingsBarButton
    }
}
```

**This version does work**

```
class DecksController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupNavigationBar()
    }

    @objc func presentSettings() {
        let settingsController = SettingsController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsController, animated: true)
    }

    func setupNavigationBar() {
        let settingsBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "settings"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(presentSettings))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = settingsBarButton
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you create `DecksController`?

Comment: DecksController is where this all lives. It’s a card-based app and I have this settings bar button in the navigation bar of the VC that displays a user’s decks. This VC appears via a tab bar controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, it makes a big difference where this line occurs:

```
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "settings"), 
    style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(presentSettings))
```

The problem is the `target:self` part. When the bar button item is configured as part of an instance property initializer (your first example), the instance doesn't exist yet — it is what we are initializing. So `self` has no meaning, and the button ends up with no `target`. Therefore, tapping the button does nothing.

(Actually, to be quite technical, `self` is the class, but that's not a helpful thing to know.)

In your second example, that line is part of `viewDidLoad`, which runs considerably *after* the view controller instance has come into existence and has been initialized. `viewDidLoad` is an instance method, in fact. So `self` is the instance, as you expect.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation—it makes sense now!

Comment: If it's any comfort, people fall into this trap all the time (setting a `target` in an instance property initializer). In my opinion, it's a bug — that is, Swift should at least issue a warning when you do it, saying that this isn't going to work the way you think it should. See https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4865

Comment: The first line could also be fixed if you change the `let` keyword into a `lazy var`. By doing that the problem of `target: self` would be the `self` you expect.

Comment: Thank you for this information. You've both been so helpful!